# Como fazer para que o crontab rode um script em Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron

Eu estou tentando agendar um script que escrevi em Python para rodar no *crontab*, porém não estou conseguindo fazê-lo.
O script é coisa simples, ele faz uma conexão telnet através do terminal e envia alguns comandos.
Eu consegui agendar um *shellscript*, porém não estou conseguindo agendar o script Python.

Tentei agendar das seguintes formas no crontab:

```
* * * * * /root/pasta/script.py
* * * * * /root/pasta/script.py > /dev/tty1
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /root/pasta/script.py
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /root/pasta/script.py > /dev/tty1
```

Coloquei no início do script `#!/usr/bin/python` e também não foi.

O script funciona normalmente no terminal, só não quer funcionar no agendamento do crontab.

O Python é o padrão do Ubuntu, versão 2.7.6.

**Segue o código Python:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os;

# Conecta no servidor telnet e envia uma mensagem.
# O servidor responde com um 'ok'.
os.system("""
(echo 'teste';
sleep 1;
echo 'quit';
exit) | telnet localhost 23""");
```

Comment: Verifique as permissões do arquivo.

Comment: Tente tornar o arquivo executável: `chmod +x /root/pasta/script.py`

Comment: O script está com permissão 777, coloquei a pasta também com 777 e continua no mesmo problema, o terminal roda sem problemas no "./script.py", mas o crontab não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui fazer funcionar...
Na verdade eu não sei qual era o problema, mas depois de reiniciar o sistema inteiro ele começou a funcionar certinho.
Se for útil para alguém, o meu crontab ficou assim:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /root/pasta/script.py
```

Valeuu pessoal!

Answer (score 0):

Em 2021

- - - - - /usr/bin/python3 /root/pasta/script.py

Funcionou desta forma, colocando a versão do python que usei.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).